# Select rows based on the values in a column

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, select

I have an Excel file with a userform where users can insert exchange rates and different parameters for financial report.

I set up a DB file and I want to select rows based on the values in BV column (book value) and it should be higher than 100.000EUR.

The problem is that I have three other currencies besides EUR and I need to calculate EUR amount based on exchange rate.

I made an exchange rate field in my userform (BVAL is EUR default, and I also have BVGBP, BVPLN and BVRSD, which are 100.000EUR divided by each exchange rate).

This works:

```
SqlQuery = " SELECT * FROM Sheet1 where (bv>=" & BVAL & " and Currency = 'EUR')";"
```

But when I try to combine multiple results, syntax is not working. I tried other solutions found online.

```
SqlQuery = " SELECT * FROM Sheet1 where (bv>=" & BVAL & " and Currency='EUR') or (bv>=" & BVGBP & " and  Currency='GBP') _
or (bv>=" & BVPLN & " and  Currency='PLN') or (bv>=" & BVRSD & " and  Currency='RSD');"
```

Comment: Use parameters. Not string concatenation.

Comment: Edit question to show sample raw data and desired output as text tables. What does 'not working' mean - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? What are BVGBP, BVPLN and BVRSD - VBA variables?

Answer (score 0):

You SQL syntax is correct, but your VBA is not. Also, for better readability, break up the long lines:

```vb
SqlQuery = " SELECT * FROM Sheet1 where " & _
    "(bv>=" & BVAL & " and Currency='EUR') or " & _
    "(bv>=" & BVGBP & " and Currency='GBP') or " & _
    "(bv>=" & BVPLN & " and Currency='PLN') or " & _
    "(bv>=" & BVRSD & " and Currency='RSD');"
```